# Java test the UI using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing some unit tests for an UI implementation. The problem that I came across is that I can't add a certain component to a container.

A quick example:

I have declared a `JComboBox myComboBox`.

The problem is when I call `myComboBox.getParent()` I get a `null` value. 
This causes further problems and my tests fail.

I have to specify that I'm using `Mockito` for testing and that the combo box was declared with the `@Mock` annotation before. My assumption is that because I use mocked objects I get this error.

So the question is: `Does anyone have any ideas how to add my mocked component to a parent container, so that it won't be null?` Or should I change the mocking framework and use `JMock`?

Answer (score 1):

Testing the UI is no easy job. As the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading) states, all components must be accessed on the Event Dispatching Thread.

Frameworks like [assertj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html) may be a help.